# Make a visual representation of a graph

Tags: linux, graph

I have a list of edges.

```
(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,7),(3,4),(3,7),(4,5),(4,7),(5,6),(6,7)
```

How can I get an image of this graph?

It should be automatic, because there are over 9000(not kidding) those lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw it with Python and `networkx`.

```
import networkx
import pylab
edges = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,7),(3,4),(3,7),(4,5),(4,7),(5,6),(6,7)]
G = networkx.Graph(data=edges)
networkx.draw(G)
pylab.show()
```

You should read `pylab`'s documentation on how to save the graph as an image without using the GUI. You can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the original lists. For example, if it stored as one graph on a line in a file, you can do:

```
with open('edges.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        edges = list(ast.literal_eval(line))
        # drawing goes here
```

Comment: If I want that in (a,b) edge `a` always draw upper than `b`, what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

I have always used [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) for this sort of stuff.

Comment: Specifically, there's a command called `dot` which lays out graph. It's really easy to use.